# Issue installing scikit-learn-0.14.1 on Mac 10.9.2

Tags: python, macos, scikit-learn

I'm getting the following error following `pip install -U scikit-learn`.  Any ideas are greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
error: Command "c++ -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64
  -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv
  -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wshorten-64-to-32
  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE
  -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe
  -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include 
  -c sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/libsvm_template.cpp
  -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/libsvm_template.o"
  failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `easy_install` instead. This [blog post](http://mentally-physically-spiritually-strong.com/2013/11/07/pythonista-installs-all-the-things/) covers the steps to get through installing scikit-learn  on MacOSX.